# Outlook Sleep without hanging GUI

Tags: vba, outlook

## Scenario

I am attempting to check if the user has the Outlook Window Focused (and the computer is not locked) on a loop (about 30 seconds). However, I don't want the GUI to be unusable in this instance, and have since used the following code to attempt to have usability. I want to know how long it takes users to write messages while the computer is not locked. (EX. In the middle of writing an email, and computer locked)

## Code

```
Private Sub Wait(ByVal DurationMS As Long)
   Dim EndTime As Long
   EndTime = GetTickCount + DurationMS
   Do While EndTime > GetTickCount
       Sleep 1
       DoEvents
   Loop
End Sub

Function CheckUnlock()
    If Check_If_Locked = "Unlocked" Then
        UnlockStatus = "Unlocked"
        Call InsertText
        Wait 30000
        Call AAA
        Call CheckUnlock
    Else
        myFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\outlook-info.csv"

        Open myFile For Append As #1
        nowTime = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
        Print #1, "COMPUTER LOCKED:" + "," + CStr(nowTime)
        Close #1

        Wait 300000
        Call CheckUnlock
    End If
End Function

Function Check_If_Locked() As String
    Dim p_lngHwnd As Long
    Dim p_lngRtn As Long
    Dim p_lngErr As Long
    p_lngHwnd = OpenDesktop(lpszDesktop:="Default", dwFlags:=0, fInherit:=False, dwDesiredAccess:=DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP)
    If p_lngHwnd = 0 Then
        system = "Error"
    Else
        p_lngRtn = SwitchDesktop(hDesktop:=p_lngHwnd)
        p_lngErr = Err.LastDllError

        If p_lngRtn = 0 Then
            If p_lngErr = 0 Then
                system = "Locked"
            Else
                system = "Error"
            End If
        Else
            system = "Unlocked"
        End If
        p_lngHwnd = CloseDesktop(p_lngHwnd)
    End If
    Check_If_Locked = system
End Function
```

## Problem

While the GUI Responds, it hangs when folders change and I know it's **because** of the sleep function, however, I'm not sure why the folders are the only ones affected by this. Emails respond fine.

Thanks in advance, any help is welcomed.

Comment: _How_ do you know it's because of the sleep function?

Comment: Because When I change the Sleep function values it causes lag for the rest of the program. Sure, I only _assume_ that it's the sleep function, but I think I have pretty good reason to suspect, as the sleep function does freeze the GUI.

Comment: Where is the code for your sleep function? Are you using the WinAPI version? if so why not just pass the `DurationMS` argument directly to `Sleep` ?

Comment: The *immediate* problem with your code is that you wait one full second before calling `doEvents`.  But you really need to think of a different, timer-based, approach for doing what you're trying to do here.  A timer-driven routine going off once per second could, for instance, count the number of consecutive times that it finds that the window is on-top.  Interesting things should start to happen when that number reaches `30` ...

Comment: @MikeRobinson Doesn't Sleep take it's parameter in Milliseconds?

Comment: Why do you want to know this?  If you can explain what you are trying to achieve we might be able to suggest an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.application_events.aspx) based approach.

Comment: @MacroMan I just tried that with the same result.

Comment: @destination-data I put what I want to do in the "Scenario" section, is there anything I can add that would be helpful?

Comment: Actually, Pizzaface, now that you mention it ... But still, "this is 'busy waiting.'"

Comment: @MikeRobinson I just see no other way to accomplish the task, as there is no inbuilt "Timer" function.

Comment: But why do you want to know when the app has the focus and the workstation is unlocked?  What will you do with this information?  What will action will it trigger?  There may be a better method to trigger said action but its hard to say without knowing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I can't dumpster-dive into this now.  Pursue destination-data's suggestion.  Explain more, so that an event-based solution can be constructed.

Comment: Why don;t you just _force_ the application take focus instead using `AppActivate()` or use the `hWnd` property?

Comment: @destination-data I added some more info to the scenario section, please let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: @MacroMan Because I want the computer to still be usable, I believe AppActivate would not allow users to say, browse the web.

Comment: `AppActivate()` brings a window to the front, that's it. It doesn't make anything freeze. VBA code running in general on the other hand will make an application unusable unless the code you have written is event driven. Perhaps if you actually gave some background in what you are trying to achieve we could help some more. This seems like an XY Problem tbh

Comment: @MacroMan I am trying to log user interactions and their corresponding time of run within Outlook. I have event driven items, such as When an Item is sent, as well as when an item is received. What I am trying to accomplish here is to not track the time when the computer is locked. I don't know of any events that would trigger when this event occurs. I'd love to hear any ideas you have. What I was trying to say about AppActivate is that it causes the focus to Change, which is not what I want.

Comment: @Pizzaface You can't do this with VBA. VBA runs on a single thread so when it runs the application isn't useable. If you want to use something this complex you need to look at using a VSTO addin or something similar that can run on multiple threads and handle event triggers in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Outlook's [explorer object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860356.aspx) to recieve [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh211482(v=office.14).aspx) notifications.  The example below pops a message box each time the main Outlook window gains or loses the focus.  Locking your PC will remove the focus.

**Example**

```
Private WithEvents e As Explorer        ' Explorer object, represents main window.


Private Sub Application_Startup()
' Register for events.

    Set e = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Quit()
' Unregister.

    Set e = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub e_Activate()
' Fired when outlook is selected.

    MsgBox "Active"
End Sub

Private Sub e_Deactivate()
' Fired when Outlook loses the focus, including on lock.

    MsgBox "Not Active"
End Sub
```

Add your own code to the activate and deactivate events, to customise.

Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869972.aspx) to the Microsoft documentation, which you might find helpful.

Comment: This worked when I switched the `Set` commands. Thanks so much!

Comment: Whoops!  Thanks I'll fix.